# Haskell - parseTime: how to verify a date-string's format AND validity

Tags: haskell

`parseTime :: ParseTime t => TimeLocale -> String -> String -> Maybe t`

This function checks the format of it's third argument (date string) using it's second (format string, for example 'YYYY-MM-DD').
However, it does not check the date's validity - instead it rounds to the closest valid date.

```
import System.Locale
import Data.Time
parseTime defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%m-%d" "2015-01-99" :: Maybe Day
```

`Just 2015-01-31`

What I'd like is to get  a valid date, or error.

Comment: As a hack, you could parse/unparse and check whether you got your string back.

Comment: Thanks, but this raises a problem, for example parseTime returns the same value for both `2015-1-31` and `2015-01-31`, so a string has to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question! As far as I know, you can't do this.

It would be an excellent feature to request on the github issue tracker, however: https://github.com/haskell/time